# Is there a way to remove all the transforms when using pdf2htmlex

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf2htmlex

I am using pdf2htmlex through docker, this is my command

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX --embed-image 0 sample.pdf
```

everything works fine but I need to process the CSS further and the transforms make it hard to get the real values for fonts and positioning, I am assuming this has something to do with scaling but I am not doing any scaling when transforming the file, is there a flag I need to use to get it to work without transforms?